# Recover lost mysql data

Tags: mysql, recovery

I accidentally executed a sql script that dropped all the tables of my database. The good thing is I have a master slave replication set-up but my slave hasn't been updated for the past 7 days.

So I was thinking if I can rollback the binlogs position to *undo* the changes made by the script.

Running `SHOW BINARY LOGS;` gave me:

```
"Log_name"  "File_size"
"mst-bin.000001"    "1073883720"
"mst-bin.000002"    "1073742741"
"mst-bin.000003"    "1073743121"
"mst-bin.000004"    "1073744456"
"mst-bin.000005"    "1073742926"
"mst-bin.000006"    "1073744758"
"mst-bin.000007"    "1073741932"
"mst-bin.000008"    "1073742250"
"mst-bin.000009"    "1073741889"
"mst-bin.000010"    "1073745312"
"mst-bin.000011"    "1073742485"
"mst-bin.000012"    "1073743060"
"mst-bin.000013"    "316454512"
"mst-bin.000014"    "1073744018"
"mst-bin.000015"    "1073741967"
"mst-bin.000016"    "1073741933"
"mst-bin.000017"    "1073742186"
"mst-bin.000018"    "828840943" // i believe this is the affected binlog
```

What are my options here? After running the script I immediately disabled the database server to freeze everything.

---

I tried  `./mysqlbinlog.exe --start-datetime="2017-02-21 12:01:57" ../data/mst-bin.000018` which is the time the script got executed and I saw everything the script executed.

The last position right before the script started executing drops has this info:

```
# at 828841094
#170221 12:06:15 server id 1  end_log_pos 828841169     Query   thread_id=66    exec_time=0     error_code=0
```

Comment: See [Point-in-Time (Incremental) Recovery Using the Binary Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/point-in-time-recovery.html)?

Comment: @eggyal I've been looking into this and currently trying to create a `recovery.sql` by dumping each binlog into a sql file. Will try to execute that sql file into the server. Hopefully the BINARY columns won't get screwed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Point-in-Time (Incremental) Recovery Using the Binary Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/point-in-time-recovery.html) worked for me.

First I looked for the position of the binlog right before the accident. Which I found was: `828841094`. Then I executed this command:

```
./mysqlbinlog.exe --stop-position=828841094 ../data/mst-bin.000001 ../data/mst-bin.000002 ../data/mst-bin.000003 ...so on ../data/mst-bin.000018 | ./mysql.exe --binary-mode --binary-mode -u root -p
```

The `--stop-position` will only apply to the last bin file on the list.

And it replayed all the queries which took a lot of time but at least I recovered the data.

Thanks to @eggyal for the suggestion.