# How to Revert import Schema in Mysql Work Bench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have exported a schema xyz from my local sever and imported in staging server with new schema name, But I haven't observed there is a schema already available in staging server xyz.

Now workbench didn't consider the new schema name that I've given and dropped staging xyx tables and imported the new data.

How can I revert this, I really need this data.

I totally missed this note:

> The default schema to import the dump into. NOTE: this is only used if
> the dump file doesn't contain its schema, otherwise it is ignored.
> Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sounds like you should restore the data from the most recent backup

Comment: @NicoHaase, Unfortunately I don't have a recent backup.

Comment: Then you learnt a valuable lesson today. Always have back-ups

Comment: Do you have binary logs and a delayed replica? Check this answer, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374958/recover-lost-mysql-data